# Restkit 0.20 creating a chain of requests

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've used restkit 0.10 for a while and now i have updated to 0.20 with a new project im working on.

With this updated version, the didloadobject delegate method is no longer available and i have to use completion blocks for success o failed requests.

So.. basically I would like a little direction about how to use restkit with these completion blocks and how would be a nice clean approach when i have to do several requests when every request i do needs data from the previous request.

For example if i have this code

REQUEST 1

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
       [call request2WithDataFromThisRequest];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fail!");
    }];
```

REQUEST 2

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
       [call requestNWithDataFromRequest1];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fail!");
    }];
```

This is the only approach i'm thinking of right now.. and i don't know if there's any better

Any help is appreciated.

Regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).
You can setup dependencies between NSOperations.

> Dependencies are a convenient way to execute operations in a specific order. You can add and remove dependencies for an operation using the [addDependency:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/addDependency%3a) and [removeDependency:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/removeDependency%3a) methods. By default, an operation object that has dependencies is not considered ready until all of its dependent operation objects have finished executing. Once the last dependent operation finishes, however, the operation object becomes ready and able to execute.

I can also recommend to listen to [042 iPhreaks Show – Concurrency with Jeff Kelley](http://iphreaksshow.com/042-iphreaks-show-concurrency-with-jeff-kelley/).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use data from a previous request and you need the next request sent as soon as the previous one completes then you need to do something like you have. Pass the `mappingResult` (or some of its content) to the next method so it knows what to do.

I'd say your scenario is a little irregular, certainly for multiple chained requests. Most requests should be user driven, perhaps with one follow on request...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I know, i have the example of a bank app i've been working on, when the user presses continue or accept, there are different requests made to the server.

```
example:

request1: is it on stock market hours

request2: if(is on stock market hours) do .. get account data

request3: do invest with account data
```

Maybe i should aim for the server to do every request by itself and return the final result..

Comment: You should not write an answer when what you want to do is comment on a different answer. Use the comment function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another framework such as [Bolts-iOS](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) to wrap your requests in "tasks" and chain the tasks together, feeding the response of one into the next.